# android - intent resolution rule - uri & mime type

Tags: android, android-intent

One of Android's intent resolution rule is :

```
An intent that contains a URI but no MIME type (neither explicit 
nor inferable from the URI) passes the test only if its URI 
matches the filter's URI format and the filter likewise does 
not specify a MIME type.
```

I am not able to understand the `inferable from the URI` part. I tried to find some example; I think [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Calendar) one matches this case :

```
public void addEvent(String title, String location, Calendar begin, Calendar end) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
        .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
        .putExtra(Events.TITLE, title)
        .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, begin)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, end);
  if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}

<activity ...>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/event" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The Intent has URI, but no mime type. The intent filter has no URI, but has mime type.

Can some one explain how the mime type is inferred from uri here ? (It has to be otherwise the intent can't pass this filter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android calls [ContentResolver.getType(Uri)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getType%28android.net.Uri%29) to determine an inferred type given only a uri.

Comment: That's right for uris with `content` scheme. For uris with `file` scheme, I presume the MIME type is inferred from the file extension. Using `MimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension` perhaps. It would be nice if someone can point to the code in AOSP where this resolution is taken.

Comment: @JuanAndrés - looking at [IntentFilter.match()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/IntentFilter.java), it only calls [Intent.resolveType](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java) and does no processing for `file` schemes.

Comment: My testing shows that `getContentResolver().getType(data)` does a rather poor job. A Uri such as `file:///storage/emulated/0/myfiles/IMG_183150.jpg` or  `content://com.example.fileprovider/MyFiles/IMG_183150.jpg` both return null.

Comment: @EdwardFalk - looking at the [source of FileProvider](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.java#439) a null mime type is not possible. If you could file a bug at [b.android.com](http://b.android.com) with a sample project, I'd love to take a look.

Comment: I'm only calling `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to get the Uri. I use that to construct an Intent and send it along. I'm not setting the mime type in the intent. I was hoping that the receiver could call `getContentResolver().getType(data)` to infer the mime type. That's the part that's not working. I could call `FileProvider.getType()` and use it to add the type to the intent, but that would mean instantiating **FileProvider**, wouldn't it? I already have code that uses **MimeTypeMap**, which is what I was planning to use here.

Comment: @EdwardFalk - you can't use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` without also [setting up your `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html) by adding it your manifest and configuring it. As per [this post](https://medium.com/@ianhlake/action-view-is-an-entirely-different-beast-from-action-send-what-sharecompat-uses-so-it-is-100-5cd03e3d60de), if you're using `setData()` with a `FileProvider` provided URI, the type is indeed inferred by the system calling `getType()` for you.

Comment: OK, never mind. I don't know what I changed, but `getContentResolver().getType(data)` is working now. Thanks for your help. (Still doesn't work for file:// URIs, but I think that's to be expected.)